# Javascript alert position not in center in chrome

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, alert

When I'm using an javascript alert it's going on top of the browser, **not in center** position in current version of chrome. How can I control it, and make it center with **javascript**. In firefox and IE,it's working just fine.
My current chrome version 30.0.1599.66

I want to position the alert box in exact center of the browser for all type of browsers and for all versions. Please help........

Any other simple idea on providing alert so that it could be centered, would also be appreciable...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Being dependent upon the browsers for the alerts is not a good choice for any. They change rapidly and are not the same for different browsers.

What i have found useful is to use [Alertify JS](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/) for all the alert needs. You can customize it for your needs and it looks fabulous anyway.

Comment: I disagree, alertboxes, scrollbars, html5 attribute handling, should be left to the browser to determine, fastest most reliable way

Comment: @Ayyash Agreed! But at times browsers don't have that as innate feature and tend to vary among browsers. To maintain consistency among devices and browsers, its good to customize them to your own. Also many browsers are moving to better practices, but then, if we were to be satisfied with what's provided, what would be use of being human? :)

Comment: There's something people keep neglecting when designing interfaces, consistency between browsers is of no value because your users will usually stick to one browser, and they jump between so many websites that handle things differently, in other words, you are already breaking the consistency experience for your user the minute you upload your website :) give them something consistent, let alert boxes be what they're used to.

Comment: @Ayyash absolutely correct.. It will be weird if all the websites are showing their own alerts.. However the developers have developed a good to have plugin. they do deserve kudos. However the  use of the plugin MUST be avoided.

Answer (score 3):

Since it is a default box, u cannot position it, though u can create your own and position it accordingly..
try this
http://jqueryui.com/dialog/

Answer (score 3):

You want alert() dialog position in center. Try this simple script.js

```
// alertMX -  improve alert()

$("<style type='text/css'>#boxMX{display:none;background: #333;padding: 10px;border: 2px solid #ddd;float: left;font-size: 1.2em;position: fixed;top: 50%; left: 50%;z-index: 99999;box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 20px #999; border-radius:6px 6px 6px 6px; -moz-border-radius: 6px; -webkit-border-radius: 6px; font:13px Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif; padding:6px 6px 4px;width:300px; color: white;}</style>").appendTo("head");

function alertMX(t){
$( "body" ).append( $( "<div id='boxMX'><p class='msgMX'></p><p>CLOSE</p></div>" ) );
$('.msgMX').text(t); var popMargTop = ($('#boxMX').height() + 24) / 2, popMargLeft = ($('#boxMX').width() + 24) / 2; 
$('#boxMX').css({ 'margin-top' : -popMargTop,'margin-left' : -popMargLeft}).fadeIn(600);
$("#boxMX").click(function() { $(this).remove(); });  };
```

Include Jquery and use javascript:

```
alertMX('Hello!');
```

Answer (score 1):

You cannot control the way browser display alert. Instead, you should write your own function to display div with your message. It could be something like that:

```
function customAlert(msg) {
var alertDiv = "<div style='position: fixed; top: 20px; left: 20px;'>"+msg+"</div>";
document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(alertDiv);
}
```

Ofcourse you should do some calculation there to properly position the div where you want. Also it would be much easier if you use jQuery or some other js framework...

[Edit]
Try something like that if you want to force popup from JS.
[Popup example](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/popup.html)

Comment: Div won't work for me bro, I need pop-up alert box. Thanks for your info.

Comment: Actually in modern browsers like FF, Chrome and Opera alert boxes are in fact rendered the same way as divs - they aren't popup boxes any more. However though if you really need a popup try something like I propose in edit.