# Centering Pop Up Message - Javascript

Tags: javascript, center

How can I put this popup error message at the center of my webpage? Here is my code:

```
    echo "<script language=\"JavaScript\">\n";
    echo "alert('User does not exist!');\n";
    echo "window.location='login.php'";
    echo "</script>";
```

thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot change the position of browser alert messages or any other browser dialogs. The solution is to implement your own dialog windows or use external libraries like [ALERTIFY.js](http://fabien-d.github.io/alertify.js/). Please read this question as well: [Javascript alert position not in center in chrome](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19151560/javascript-alert-position-not-in-center-in-chrome).

Comment: Can I ask one thing? How would I check if the data I am inputting is already existing?

Comment: You gotta connect to your database and compare current data with database data....

Comment: Got it! Also, does anybody know how to set a timeout record in PHP? I'm developing an attendance system.